# dropdownlist returns value, not text

Tags: c#, html-select

I’m a newbie and am probably missing something obvious. When creating a new "Flight" the dropdownlist returns the value, e.g. “2”, rather than the desired text, e.g. “Comm”.  Breakpoints and watches verify that "FlightType" and "ViewBag" contain the correct info. Any suggestions are most welcome.

**Models:  Flight.cs**

```
public class Flight
{
    [Key]
    public int FlightID { get; set; }

    public int FlightTypeID { get; set; }
    public string FlightTypeEntry { get; set; }
}
```

**Models:  FlightType.cs**

```
public class FlightType
{
[Key]
public int FlightTypeID { get; set; }
public string FlightTypeEntry { get; set; }
}
```

**DAL:  FlightInitializer.cs**

```
var flighttypes = new List<FlightType
{
new FlightType { FlightTypeEntry = "Regular" },
new FlightType { FlightTypeEntry = "Comm" }
};
flighttypes.ForEach(e => context.FlightType.Add(e));
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Controllers:  FlightController.cs**

```
// GET: /Flight/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
ViewBag.FlightVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeID",
    "FlightTypeEntry");
return View();
}

// POST: /Flight/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Flight flight)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Flight.Attach(flight);
    db.Entry(flight).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.Flight.Add(flight);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

ViewBag.FlightTypeVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeID"
    "FlightTypeEntry");
return View(flight);
```

**Views:  Flight.Create.cshtml**

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownList(“FlightTypelID", <SelectList>)ViewBag.FlightTypeVB)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Flight object on the Create HttpPost probably isn't populating correctly b/c the dropdown list is only going to return the value of the selected item - the value in your case is "FlightTypeID". If you want to change it to return the text value "FlightTypeEntry", then you could change

```
ViewBag.FlightVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeID", "FlightTypeEntry");
```

to

```
ViewBag.FlightVB = new SelectList(db.FlightType, "FlightTypeEntry", "FlightTypeEntry");
```

I'm not sure this would be a good thing though. Either way, its not going to fully populate the Flight object  on the post-back. To do that, you may want to use hidden fields for the input flightID, and either figure out the "FlightTypeID" that corresponds to the "FlightTypeValue" or vice versa.